# Alternative for context.succeed(event)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, database-migration, amazon-cognito-triggers

Iam trying to create a migration trigger using python to change my user pool.In this trigger, what will be the alternative for `context.succeed(event)` that needs to be sent back to cognito after successful verification of user.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, you can return the **event**

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Your code here

    # Return to Amazon Cognito
    return event
```

[Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-post-authentication.html)